# crm 2011 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

The code below creates a set of records from an entity I use to hold "template" records.  I loop through the templates and create records which works including the lookup fields where I use an EntityReferenceentity.  But when I use an EntityReference to create a relationship back to the parent entity record I get this error.

> crm 2011 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'

```js
            foreach (var template in templateSteps.Entities)
            {
                Entity step = new Entity("img_workflowmanager");
                step["subject"] = template["img_name"];

                if (step.Contains("img_poststepid"))
                {
                    step["img_poststepid"] = (EntityReference)template["img_poststepid"];
                }
                if (step.Contains("img_prestepid"))
                {
                    step["img_prestepid"] = (EntityReference)template["img_prestepid"];
                }

                step["img_workflowstepsid"] = (EntityReference)postMessageImage["img_procurementpackageid"];
                this._orgService.Create(step);
            }
```

Comment: I tried this as well:
step["img_workflowstepsid"] = ((EntityReference)postMessageImage["img_procurementpackageid"]).Id;

Answer (score 8):

The message is clear, `postMessageImage["img_procurementpackageid"]` contains a Guid and not an `EntityReference`.

Assuming the entity name is `img_workflowsteps` you can write

```cs
Guid packageId = (Guid)postMessageImage["img_procurementpackageid"];
step["img_workflowstepsid"] = new EntityReference("img_workflowsteps", packageId);
```

By the way, the first two if conditions will be never executed, because when you create an entity with that syntax, no attributes are defined.

Comment: Thanks but When I use your example I get a compile error - 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference.EntityReference(string, System.Guid)' has some invalid arguments.